# Add ssh key file for linux server - Key generated, then what?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, openssh

I want to build a CentOS7 server by myself.

Now I already followed the steps mentioned in this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-centos-7, which includes

1. generated my new key .pub file using keygen.
2. add its content start with "ssh-rsa" to .ssh/authorized_keys
3. chmod the key and the .ssh folder,
4. configure sshd using  `vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
5. use `systemctl reload sshd` to restart sshd.

At this point, I thought the future ssh operations from my client host should already need the key to do the log in. However, at this point I can still using ssh to log in my server with only password.

Are there any special procedure that I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open sshd configuration file and uncomment or add line `PasswordAuthentication no`. Restart sshd service.

Answer (score 2):

> 2. add its content start with "ssh-rsa" to .ssh/authorized_keys

No... This should go on the remote system. On your personal system you keep the private key, and you add the public key to all the `/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` of all systems/userids you want to access using the key. This can be done 'manually' or using `ssh-copy-id`, typically:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/your_key.pub remote-host
```

or

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/your_key.pub user@remote-host
```

if this is a different userid.

If you do it manually, make sure that you keep the correct authorization flags on all files and .ssh directories (should be R/W strictly for that user only, no access whatsoever by anyone else).

Comment: So how to let a new client (which does not have access to the server) access to the server? Is the ssh-copy-id still gonna work?

Comment: And if I want to generate a key to be used by multiple host, should I use the public key(.pub) or no-public key?

Comment: You copy the .pub to each of the hosts. And you keep the private key on your PC.